LunarVIM `nvim-treesitter` fails with error "query: invalid node type at position" for language "c" and "cpp"
I am starting with a fresh install of lunarvim and neovim (release-1.3/neovim-0.9) and I end up with the following issue when I open a cpp file.
vim-illumintate: An internal error has occured: false" ...im/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 1032 for language cpp"

Running checkhealth nvim-treesitter gets me these errors
- ERROR c(locals): ...im/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 1032 for language c
  c(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/Users/xxx/.local/share/lunarvim/site/pack/lazy/opt/nvim-treesitter/queries/c/locals.scm", failed to load: ...im/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 1032 for language c
- ERROR cpp(locals): ...im/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 1032 for language cpp
  cpp(locals) is concatenated from the following files:
  | [ERROR]:"/Users/xxx/.local/share/lunarvim/site/pack/lazy/opt/nvim-treesitter/queries/c/locals.scm", failed to load: ...im/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 1032 for language cpp
  | [ERROR]:"/Users/xxx/.local/share/lunarvim/site/pack/lazy/opt/nvim-treesitter/queries/cpp/locals.scm", failed to load: ...im/0.9.5/share/nvim/runtime/lua/vim/treesitter/query.lua:259: query: invalid node type at position 1177 for language cpp

I have tried the following commands wihtout any success (it says everything is up to date):

TSUpdate c / TSInstall c
TSUpdate cpp / TSInstall cpp

I am kinda lost on what to do. This seems to be an incompatibility between lunarvim and neovim but really not sure...

I have tried the steps from this neovim issue to remove any unwanted parser but the result is the same

I finally have found out why.
I did not have actually a total clear configuration, there was some leftovers in the config.lua file that pointed to some other files which were doing some "weird" things that I did not understand (copy/paste from someone else configuration).
I have actually removed everything, reinstalled neovim/lunarvim and now I do not have any issue.
